# Different Hair cards for bird feathers

Tags: particles

I am trying to create a bird with feathers of gradually shifting colours and length. I use a particle system to generate lots of small feathers, but I haven't been able to find way of giving them different colours other than at random.

Is there a way to control the shader of the feather cards using the texture of the body basemesh?

I also wish to vary the length of the feather and haven't found a way to scale the particles along a specific angle. Is there a way to do that?